# Implementing BLE Paired connection in Peripheral App

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I was looking for sample codes for implementing the BLE peripheral. I was able to find few example projects for reference but I could not find APIs related to BLE pairing. As per the requirement my App(configured as a peripheral) needs to pair (using a passkey) with the central before communicating any data. Can anyone guide me?
NOTE: My development environment is iOS V11, Swift 4 and XCode 9.

Comment: You need to specify "encryption required" for your attribute - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH5-SW1